# How to specify drive name and network share in FileNameJoin

Tags: files-and-directories

The benefit of `FileNameJoin` is that you don't need to worry about the operating system's formatting of directory paths.  I need to specify a directory path to a network share and a named drive so that *Mathematica* resolves the correct format for the operating system it is running on.

For example, in Windows

> \\netShare\directory\subdirectory

and

> driveName:\directory\subdirectory

How can I specify that `"netShare"` is a network share in

```
FileNameJoin[{"netShare", "directory", "subdirectory"}]
```

and that `"driveName"` is a named drive in

```
FileNameJoin[{"driveName", "directory", "subdirectory"}]
```

such that I get the correctly formatted directory string on whichever operating system this is executed on?

Comment: did you get an answer?  If you did, can you answer your own question?